# mysql query runs slow on new MariaDb Installation

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb

I have a new centos7 server with mariadb 10.8.4, 32GB ram, AMD Ryzen 5 PRO 3600 6-Core Processor, 12 cores,
The old server is Centos7 with mariadb 5.5.68
My development machine is 2017 macbook pro

The following query runs in 0.17 seconds on my dev machine, 0.56 seconds on the old server, and 29.8 seconds on the new server!

I've tried all I can google to tune the conf of the new server and nothing improves matters.
I have tried using the conf of the old server on the new one, still no change.
Here is the conf, the commented lines are the new server conf, the others are the old..:

```
[mysqld]
#max_allowed_packet = 512M
#query_cache_size = 32M
#thread_cache_size = 8
#myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
#read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
#read_buffer_size = 2M
#sort_buffer_size = 8M
#table_open_cache = 1512
#key_buffer_size = 384M
#sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
query_cache_size = 32M
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_limit=1048576
sort_buffer_size = 8M
table_open_cache = 500
key_buffer_size = 32M
max_connections = 500
big-tables
log_error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.err
```

And the query:

```
SELECT cornishestabs.id, cornishestabs.name, townid, cornishestabs.postcode, 
        cornishestabs.latitude, cornishestabs.longitude, cornishestabs.image, 
        cornishestabs.web, cornishtowns.Name AS Town, cornishtowns.bloglink, 
        cornishtowns.blogtitle, types.title, 
        SQRT( POW( 69.1 * ( cornishestabs.latitude - '50.16304' ) , 2 ) + POW( 69.1 * ( '-5.3761' - cornishestabs.longitude ) * COS( cornishestabs.latitude / 57.3 ) , 2 ) ) AS distance
FROM cornishestabs
    INNER JOIN cornishtowns ON cornishtowns.ID = cornishestabs.townid
    INNER JOIN types ON types.id = cornishestabs.etype
WHERE cornishestabs.display = 1
AND cornishestabs.latitude > 0
AND cornishestabs.id != '60959'
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 10;
```

I am honestly at a loss as to how to proceed, I know there is some math in the query but it has never been slow before!

Thanks for the response, here are results from the 2 servers as requested:

EXPLAIN command for New Server:

```
+------+-------------+---------------+------+--------------------------------------+--------+---------+--------------------------------+------+------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table         | type | possible_keys                        | key    | key_len | ref                            | rows | Extra                              |
+------+-------------+---------------+------+--------------------------------------+--------+---------+--------------------------------+------+------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | cornishtowns  | ALL  | PRIMARY                              | NULL   | NULL    | NULL                           | 1    | Using temporary; Using filesort    |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | types         | ALL  | PRIMARY                              | NULL   | NULL    | NULL                           | 1    | Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | cornishestabs | ref  | PRIMARY,display,type,townid,latitude | townid | 2       | cornish_breaks.cornishtowns.ID | 88   | Using index condition; Using where |
+------+-------------+---------------+------+--------------------------------------+--------+---------+--------------------------------+------+------------------------------------+
```

EXPLAIN command for Old Server:

```
+------+-------------+---------------+--------+--------------------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table         | type   | possible_keys                        | key     | key_len | ref                                  | rows | Extra                                                               |
+------+-------------+---------------+--------+--------------------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | cornishestabs | ref    | PRIMARY,display,type,townid,latitude | display | 1       | const                                | 5083 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | cornishtowns  | eq_ref | PRIMARY                              | PRIMARY | 2       | stayin_cornwall.cornishestabs.townid |    1 |                                                                     |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | types         | eq_ref | PRIMARY                              | PRIMARY | 4       | stayin_cornwall.cornishestabs.etype  |    1 | Using where                                                         |
+------+-------------+---------------+--------+--------------------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And here are the SHOW CREATE results from the 2 servers.
New Server:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE cornishestabs
| cornishestabs | CREATE TABLE `cornishestabs` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `associd` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(96) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `address` text NOT NULL,
  `townid` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `postcode` varchar(34) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `descr` text NOT NULL,
  `ourdescr` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating` varchar(96) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `etype` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `etype2` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `etype3` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `etype4` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tel` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(76) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `web` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `online` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `assoc` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `moreimgs` text NOT NULL,
  `latitude` decimal(18,15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` decimal(18,15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `northing` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `easting` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `sleeps` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `pets` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `price` varchar(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `facilities` text NOT NULL,
  `brochure` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `display` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `reviewnumber` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `reviews` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `display` (`display`),
  KEY `type` (`etype`),
  KEY `etype2` (`etype2`),
  KEY `etype3` (`etype3`),
  KEY `etype4` (`etype4`),
  KEY `associd` (`associd`),
  KEY `postcode` (`postcode`),
  KEY `assoc` (`assoc`),
  KEY `townid` (`townid`),
  KEY `latitude` (`latitude`),
  KEY `longitude` (`longitude`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=73642 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 

 cornishtowns | CREATE TABLE `cornishtowns` (
  `ID` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `telcode` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `postcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `population` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` decimal(18,15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` decimal(18,15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `northing` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `easting` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `NationalPark` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `village` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `area` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `bloglink` varchar(96) NOT NULL,
  `blogtitle` varchar(48) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `Name` (`Name`),
  KEY `NationalPark` (`NationalPark`),
  KEY `northing` (`northing`),
  KEY `easting` (`easting`),
  KEY `area` (`area`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4675 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 

types | CREATE TABLE `types` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `link` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `title` varchar(96) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `typedescription` text NOT NULL,
  `shortname` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Old Server:

```
cornishestabs | CREATE TABLE `cornishestabs` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `associd` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(96) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `address` text NOT NULL,
  `townid` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `postcode` varchar(34) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `descr` text NOT NULL,
  `ourdescr` text,
  `rating` varchar(96) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `etype` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `etype2` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `etype3` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `etype4` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tel` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(76) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `web` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `online` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `assoc` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `moreimgs` text NOT NULL,
  `latitude` decimal(18,15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` decimal(18,15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `northing` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `easting` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `sleeps` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pets` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `price` varchar(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `facilities` text NOT NULL,
  `brochure` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `display` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `reviewnumber` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `reviews` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `display` (`display`),
  KEY `type` (`etype`),
  KEY `etype2` (`etype2`),
  KEY `etype3` (`etype3`),
  KEY `etype4` (`etype4`),
  KEY `associd` (`associd`),
  KEY `postcode` (`postcode`),
  KEY `assoc` (`assoc`),
  KEY `townid` (`townid`),
  KEY `latitude` (`latitude`),
  KEY `longitude` (`longitude`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=73642 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

cornishtowns | CREATE TABLE `cornishtowns` (
  `ID` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description` text,
  `telcode` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `postcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `population` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` decimal(18,15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` decimal(18,15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `northing` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `easting` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `NationalPark` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `village` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `area` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `bloglink` varchar(96) NOT NULL,
  `blogtitle` varchar(48) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `Name` (`Name`),
  KEY `NationalPark` (`NationalPark`),
  KEY `northing` (`northing`),
  KEY `easting` (`easting`),
  KEY `area` (`area`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4675 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 

types | CREATE TABLE `types` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `link` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `title` varchar(96) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `typedescription` text NOT NULL,
  `shortname` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: It's not configuration. MariaDb has significant automatic configuration features. You're probably missing some indexes from your tables on the new server. [edit] your question to show us the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE for each table. And please show us the execution plan that comes from prepending ANALYZE to your query.

Comment: A first step would be to compare the EXPLAIN plan on the different systems to see if the execution plan is the same or -- more likely -- differs. We can then continue from there ...

Comment: Yes, the explanations for each server are different! I hope you can make some sense of it :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the "why" of the timing differences, please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for each server.

To improve the speed of "find the nearest", see [*Find Nearest*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql)

As for configuration -- One cannot [usually] use configuration to significantly improve performance.  In particular, none of the listed items (even the commented-out ones) could cause that level of speed difference.  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size?  How much RAM do you have?  Usually, it is better to turn off the Query cache.

Nor do the hardware configurations justify such a huge difference.

Comment: I like your link to 'find nearest', that's certainly food for thought!